# True/false: If two finite abelian groups of the same order have equal sum of element orders, then they are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Is it true that: **If two finite abelian groups of the same order have equal sum of element orders, then they are isomorphic**?

I have tried getting a counterexample, but failed.

So as not to be misunderstood by the term "sum of element orders," I will explain with an example.

The sum of element orders of $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$ is $1+2+2+2=7$ while that of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is $1+2+4+4=11$. This example shows that the sum of element orders of $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are not equal.

Looking forward to suggestions on how to prove the above highlighted proposition.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a fundamental [theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups) for finite abelian groups, which is like factorization in some sense. If your group is order $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, $p$'s distinct primes, then the finite abelian groups of order $n$ are $Z_{q_1}\times Z_{q_2}\times\cdots\times Z_{q_l} $ where each of the $q$'s are prime powers and the product of the $q$'s is $n$. This would at least let you(others) check specific $n$ for counterexamples if they exist.

Comment: This appears to be a place to start: http://www.math.uaic.ro/~martar/pdf/articole/articol%2056.pdf

Comment: @ snuity, I know the result. In fact, I am sure we can't get a counter example up to abelian groups of order 5000 which I have carefully checked. So I believe the proposition is true.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan judging by the conjecture $6$ (op's question) and that it was computer checked for groups of order less than 100,000, I guess 'small' counterexamples won't be found.

Comment: @ChrisDav my last comment also.

Comment: @ snuity, that's true...no small counterexample can be found. The question is very much open!

Comment: @ChrisDav: The article I mentioned proves it for abelian $p$-groups, and indicates a possible approach for the general case at the end. Not sure what more you want by way of a clue.